# JS highlight 1 value on red and 2nd value on blue

Tags: javascript, html

Im learing js atm and stumble upon this i want to highlight values greater than 1000 on red color and others on blue

this code displays this table and it works fine.

```
<tr> 
<td>1</td><td>EX</td><td>MPK</td><td class='netto'>500</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>510</td><td>500</td><td>510</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>2</td><td>EX</td><td>MPK</td><td class='netto'>1000</td><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>1040</td><td>2000</td><td>2080</td>
</tr><tr> 
<td>3</td><td>EX</td><td>MPK</td><td class='netto'>1500</td><td>3</td><td>8</td><td>1620</td><td>4500</td><td>4860</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>4</td><td>EX</td><td>MPK</td><td class='netto'>2000</td><td>4</td><td>16</td><td>2320</td><td>8000</td><td>9280</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>5</td><td>EX</td><td>MPK</td><td class='netto'>2500</td><td>5</td><td>32</td><td>3300</td><td>12500</td><td>16500</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>6</td><td>EX</td><td>MPK</td><td class='netto'>800</td><td>5</td><td>18</td><td>944</td><td><p class='demo'>4000</p></td><td>4720</td>
</tr>
```

button than activates js

```
<input type="button" value="Find greater than 1000" onclick = "find()">
```

and js code it kinda works but I still dont know what loop if i should use to highlight correct values

```
function find() {
    var td = document.getElementsByClassName('netto');
    var val = td.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
      if (val >= 1000)
        td[i].style.backgroundColor ="red";
      else
       td[i].style.backgroundColor ="blue";
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you go https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/XWKjpWM

Answer (score 0):

You can use [for each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function on td array.

Also you should check td innerHTML (instead of value) during every iteration.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('netto').forEach(element => {
 
   element.innerHTML >= 1000 ? element.style.backgroundColor = 'red' : element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue;
})
```

Comment: Also innerHTML type is string. In this case cast will be done as expected, but you could have some issue if you try to add value for example.
Use parseInt to implicitly cast value and avoid issues.

Comment: If you are going to use a ternary, might as well use it the correct way, not as an if. `element.style.backgroundColor = +element.textContent.trim() >= 1000 ? "red" : "blue";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on `textContent` not value and take in consideration that `textContent` is a string so you need to convert it to number value so you can compare correctly using `Number` method

```
// getElementsByClassName returns an HTML collection not array so we need 
// to convert it to array first so we can loop through
const td= [...document.getElementsByClassName('netto')]

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if(Number(elements[i].textContent) > 1000) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor= "green"
  }

}
```

Here is [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8fpbsyn/) example

Comment: ```innerHTML``` would give the html element so in this case using ```textContent``` would be the better approach..

Comment: yes you are right, assuming that inner HTML not always will return a text node

Comment: An HTML collection is itterable so you can use for loops on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 major errors on your code :

First td is an array, so **td.value** is undefined.

Secondly **value** refer to the element field "value".

If you had < td value="500" > you could use it.

Here you want the content of the element.
You have to use **td.innerHTML** or **td.textContent**

Finally, **value**, **innerHTML** or **textContent** are strings. You should cast it to number before using math on it.

So the correct way using your code is

```
function find() {
  var td = document.getElementsByClassName('netto');
  for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    var val = parseInt(td[i].textContent);
    if (val >= 1000)
      td[i].style.backgroundColor ="red";
    else
      td[i].style.backgroundColor ="blue";
  }
}
```

And you could use the structure

```
const array = document.getElementsByClassName('netto');
for (let td of array )
{
    const val = td.textContent;
    /* ... */
}
```

Which is more efficient in JS.

And think about using keywords **let** and **const** to declare scope variables rather than **var**.